# Floating elements right avoiding scrollbars

Tags: css, overflow, css-float

Im trying to float an element right outside of the main page content and want to avoid the horizontal scroll bar from cutting it off

**Example**
http://www.warface.co.uk/clients/warface.co.uk/test

I've noticed its been achieved in the footer here, but can't figure it out how
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    wrapper

<div class="imageright">
    </div><!-- imageright END -->

</div><!-- wrapper END -->
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    background: yellow;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width: 1140px;
    height:500px;
    }

.imageright {
    background: aqua;
    width:520px;
    height:285px;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    float:right;
    right:-100px;
    }
```

Comment: It's an illusion if I'm reading the source code correctly, it's just a large image if you're talking about the background image.

Comment: For webdesignerdepot, are you refering to how the date are displayed or how the top banner is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position: absolute;` and the `right:-100px;` is pushing your element past the right edge of the viewport.  Floating does not affect absolutely positioned elements.

If you want the element to be `100px` away from the edge, make that a positive `100px`.  Or, if you want it right up against the edge, make it `0`.  If you truly want to float it, remove the absolute positioning.

Hopefully I understood the question, and I hope this helps!

Edit: I re-read the question and think an even better solution would be to add `position: relative;` to the wrapper.  Right now, your absolutely position element is positioned relative to the viewport.  If you give `wrapper` relative positioning, it will cause `imageright` to be positioned relative to `wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

you *can* apply `overflow:hidden;` to the body, which is how you get what you're after, but it's highly inadvisable.  Another way to take the div "out of flow" is to make it `position: fixed;` but that will mean it will be visible as you scroll down.